# MSAL: Is it possible to get the sign in status without bringing up a popup?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm trying to create a single page application which allows a basic Google or Microsoft user to sign in. With [Google Sign in for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), when a user signs in and permits access, the user is not prompted for sign in during subsequent visits to my website. My javascript can check to see if the user is signed in, and do the needful.

With MSAL, however, there is no way to check if the user is currently logged in. It seems that my javascript has to call userAgentApplication.loginPopup() to check if the user has logged in or not. This will always cause a popup to be displayed, even if the user has already signed in (and permitted access).

Is there any way I can call a function in javascript to find out whether the user had already signed in earlier?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the flow below. It uses `acquireTokenSilent` to try to check the current token. The flow below makes use of it, with a error checking to bring up the popup only when needed.

```
getToken = () => {
  return this.app.acquireTokenSilent(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(
    accessToken => {
      console.log('accessToken :', accessToken)
      return accessToken
    },
    error => {
      console.log('error :', error)
      return this.app
        .acquireTokenPopup(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes)
        .then(
          accessToken => {
            return accessToken
          },
          err => {
            console.error(err)
          }
        )
    }
  )
}
```